# IOS/Objective-C: Date Format for ICS file

Tags: ios, nsdate

I need to convert a date stored as an NSDate in core data into the following format for an ICS file.  Should I use an NSDateFormatter or can anyone suggest how to do this?  Thank you.

```
NSString *start = @"DTSTART:20140318T111000Z";
```

My date in core data is created using `[NSDate date]`.

To be honest, I don't know what it looks like in sqlite as I haven't been able to get a browser working to view sqlite file.

However, it logs to console as:

```
2017-01-28 02:44:59 +0000
```

Comment: Yes, use `NSDateFormatter`. There are countless examples showing how.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using DateFormatter and the format is "yyyyMMdd\'T\'HHmmss\'Z\'"